# Is there a way to tag multiple assets with the same tag?

Tags: asset-browser

I am just getting started with organising assets with the built-in asset browser in Blender 3.3 I like the tag feature but it seems a bit limited since there doesn't appear to be a way to tag multiple assets at once. I have tried alt+clicking but it seems that this behaviour hasn't been added in this part of the UI.

Is there an addon or a simple script or other way to tag multiple assets at once?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found an addon that allows a number of batch operations in the asset browser, including tag multiple assets: https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities